# Griddle Subgrids Collapse on Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

[Griddle](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/index.html) supports [subgrids](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/subgrids.html). I have a custom component (used for row selection) in one of the fields that changes the state. This state change causes a re-render, which collapses the subgrid. However, I'd like it to stay open.

This same problem is documented in this Github [issue](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/115), including this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zcpf1gfs/) (thanks @denzelby of Github) in which filtering collapses the subgrids.

Note in the code from the fiddle how the state is updated `onCountClick` (clicking the "inc" button), causing the re-render:

```
var GridAndCounter = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
  var columnNames = ['id', 'age', 'name', 'company', 'state', 'country', 'favoriteNumber'];
  var rowMetadata = {key: "id"};
    return <div><Counter count={this.state.count} onClick={this.onCountClick} /><Griddle results={fakeData} rowMetadata={rowMetadata} columnNames={columnNames} resultsPerPage={100} showFilter={true} /></div>
  },
  onCountClick: function() {
      React.addons.Perf.start();
      this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1 });
      setTimeout(function() {
          React.addons.Perf.stop();
          React.addons.Perf.printDOM();
      }, 500);
  },
  getInitialState: function() { 
      return { count: 0 }; 
  }
})
```

This state update causes a re-render which sets everything to collapsed. How can I keep everything expanded on re-render? I could perhaps track which ones are expanded myself, but then I would need a programmatic way to expand the rows, which I haven't discovered with Griddle.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the github [source of Griddle](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/master/scripts/gridRowContainer.jsx), `gridRowContainer.jsx` uses **state** to determine whether the row is collapsed or not, and forces `showChildren` to `false` in its `getInitialState()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Two possible causes:

1. `componentWillReceiveProps()` is called whenever props change - and there are lots of props unrelated to 'showing children', so any prop change could introduce the unwanted side-effect you describe!

   **Suggestion:** Try removing the setting of `showChildren` in `componentWillReceiveProps()` of `gridRowContainer.jsx`
2. Less likely: If Griddle is creating entirely new components with each change of the filter (I haven't checked!), then `getInitialState()` would cause all rows to collapse. It would then need a considerable rewrite of the parent components to preserve showChildren.
3. I thought about storing `showChildren` in the data itself, and passing *your container's* handler function `setShowChildren` through to the `gridRowContainer.jsx` component (as you might do with redux), but that would get messy.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions. I attempted #1 but with no success. It seems it does recreate the whole component. Griddle 1.0 is in the works, so maybe we'll see a better or more native approach then.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an year old but if some one is still looking for answer, this is how I implemented it.

1. In `griddle.jsx.js`, while creating `GridTable`, add this prop to
   that list on line 836

   > resultsFromFilter: !this.isNullOrUndefined(this.state.filteredResults)
2. In `gridTable.jsx.js`, add `"resultsFromFilter": false` to default pass down `resultFromFilter` prop while creating `GridRowContainer` on line 180.

   > resultsFromFilter: that.props.resultsFromFilter
3. In `gridRowContainer.jsx.js`, add `resultsFromFilter: false` to list of default props and add this function to component.

   > ```
   > componentDidMount(){this.setState({showChildren:this.props.resultsFromFilter})}.
   > ```

This will ensure that when ever the sub grid matches the result comes out as collapsed.